# Sealing a pass-phrase with the TPM and associating it with a file state

Tags: disk-encryption, tpm

Is there a way to associate the state of an arbitrary file to a tpm2 PCR value? I want to seal a secret pass-phrase onto the TPM, and I want the TPM to be able to unseal it only if the file is not tampered with. I read through a related article in the [link](https://lwn.net/Articles/674751/) which talks about protecting the boot process using the TPM. Furthermore, I understand that different platform configuration registers are allocated to a state of components like BIOS, BIOS configuration, MBR, etc. However, I want to create a pcr policy that will control the access of sealed pass-phrase on TPM2 based on the checksum of a file. But I don't know how to create it. Please help me understand if this is possible.

Comment: What OS you are targeting?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Ubuntu 20.04 you can directly use tpm2-tools to seal an object against TPM2.0

Download latest tpm2-tools from Ubuntu repo or from [tpm2-tools](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools)

1. First, create the primary key using [tpm2_createprimary](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_createprimary.1.md)

   - tpm2_createprimary -C e -g <hash_algo> -G <Key_ALGO>-c primary.ctx
   - Save primary.ctx
2. Now list the PCR using [tpm2_pcrread](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_createprimary.1.md)

   - tpm2_pcrread
3. After listing the PCR, select the appropriate PCR for sealing the data.

   - There are some reserved PCR's.
   - [Link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4302-6584-9_12#Tab1)
   - Over here, you can either use the reserved PCR (e.g. PCR0) or extend another PCR.
   - Example for extending the PCR

     - [tpm2_pcrextend](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_pcrextend.1.md) 3:sha1=4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83
     - Extend the PCR 3 with sha1 value of 4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83
4. Get the PCR-read data in file

   - tpm2_pcrread -o <output_pcr_file>
   - Example format for PCR value : "<BANK>:<PCR>[,<PCR>] or <BANK>:all"
   - Where BANK is sha1 or sha2 as per supported algorithm
   - Save output PCR file
   - Example using current PCR0:

     - tpm2_pcrread -o pcr.data sha256:0
     - This will seal the data corresponding to your system state in case of trusted boot.
5. Start tpm2 authsession [Check Notes below]

   - [tpm2_startauthsession](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_startauthsession.1.md) -S <session_file>
   - Save session file
6. Create a PCR policy

   - [tpm2_policypcr](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_policypcr.1.md) -S <session_file> -l <PCR BANK> -f <output_pcr_file> -L <policy_file>
   - Save policy file
   - Flush context: tpm2_flushcontext <session_file>
7. Create object using the policy data, which we will further seal

   - [tpm2_create](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_create.1.md) -Q -u key.pub -r key.priv -C primary.ctx -L policy.dat -i <<<        [Input_DATA]
   - Save key.pub and key.priv
   - Over here, input data could be the pass-phrase or key
8. Load the Public and private portion

   - [tpm2_load](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_load.1.md) -C primary.ctx -u key.pub -r key.priv -n unseal.key.name -c unseal.key.ctx
   - save the unseal.key.ctx
9. Satisfy Policy:

   - tpm2_startauthsession --policy-session -S <session_file>
   - tpm2_policypcr -S <session_file> -l <PCR_BANK> -f <pcr_output_file> -L <policy_file>
10. Now using the unseal.key.ctx you can unseal the data

    - [tpm2_unseal](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_unseal.1.md) -psession:<session_file> -c unseal.key.ctx

NOTE: It is possible in Ubuntu 20.04 there is already Kernel resource manager for TPM2 enabled. Using tpm2_startauthsession will ease out the things

> I've used the latest tpm2-tools version.

Comment: My understanding is that I should first create a hash of the file (that I wish not to be tampered with) and extend it to the corresponding PCR bank. Then follow your procedure to seal a secret using the PCR policy that uses the specific PCR bank value. Is that right?

Comment: @Vinmean Yes, you are correct. I've updated the answer as well.

Comment: Sealing a passphrase will not protect the password from unauthorized access. If your goal is to ensure the integrity of the passphrase or ensure that the passphrase is protected in case of a stolen disk, then this procedure is fine. Otherwise, I recommend encrypting the passphrase with the key stored in TPM and seal the key.